# Page doesn't load when I'm listening PHP debug connections

Tags: php, phpstorm, xdebug

I have Windows 10, PhpStorm 2019.3.3, my files are at the localhost using XAMPP.

I have XDebug on my PhpStorm. I installed a Chrome extension named "XDebug helper".

When I stop listening to PHP debug connections it works fine. But when I click "Start listening PHP debug connections" I can't open my PHP files on my
localhost via Chrome.

When I click "Debugt db2.php" button, I get this message in the console:

> `C:\xampp\php\php.exe -dxdebug.remote_enable=1 -dxdebug.remote_mode=req -dxdebug.remote_port=9000 -dxdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1 C:\xampp\htdocs\Modul3\db2.php`

How is debugging in PhpStorm supposed to work?

Comment: Please check https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/debugging-with-phpstorm-ultimate-guide.html

Comment: please also check https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/documentation/debugging/